# Purpose of the "$=" or "?=" in lit-element examples

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, lit-element

I'm having trouble understanding the use of `?=` or `$=` these two examples:

#### First Example: [Lit-Element README](https://github.com/kenchris/lit-element/blob/master/README.md)

```
<div id="box" class$="${this.uppercase ? 'uppercase' : ''}">
  <slot>Hello World</slot>
</div>
```

#### Second Example: [PWA Example App](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/books/blob/master/src/components/book-input-decorator.js#L76)

```
<div class="decorator" focused?="${_focused}">
  <slot id="inputSlot" name="input"></slot>
  <div class="underline"></div>
</div>
```

Why do these HTML attributes have a `$` or `?` suffix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` and `?` suffixes appear to be deprecated versions of no prefix (attribute value binding) and `?` prefix ([boolean attribute binding](https://polymer.github.io/lit-html/guide/writing-templates.html#binding-types)), going by [the source](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/blob/4c627e7a14478243e8d7c797a53e96e3984e586d/src/lib/lit-extended.ts#L33-L59).

> To set an attribute instead of a property, append a `$` suffix to the attribute name.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> html`<button class$="primary">Buy Now</button>`
> ```
>
> ⋮
>
> @deprecated Please use /lit-html.js instead. lit-extended will be removed in a future version.

So you’ll want this now:

```
<div id="box" class="${this.uppercase ? 'uppercase' : ''}">
  <slot>Hello World</slot>
</div>
```

```
<div class="decorator" ?focused="${_focused}">
  <slot id="inputSlot" name="input"></slot>
  <div class="underline"></div>
</div>
```

’course, if that deprecated stuff is left in, who knows how relevant the rest of their contexts is.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to find the most current [documentation](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/blob/4c627e7a14478243e8d7c797a53e96e3984e586d/src/lit-html.ts#L31-L58). It looks like they're switching to another syntax for variables and properties.